# Why isn't the callback I pass to jQuery's animate() method called?

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate

I can't call callback after animation ends. Here is my animation function:

```
function animate( parentElement, callback )
{
        parentElement.animate({
            "height" : "hide", "opacity" : 0.0
        }, { duration : "slow"}, "linear", callback);
}
```

And here is calling it:

```
 animate( $(this).parent(), function() { alert('test'); } );
```

Alert doesn't show, why?

Comment: Why are you passing in `{ duration : "slow"}` as the second parameter? Should just be a string, e.g. `"slow"`, or a number representing an exact duration in milliseconds.

Comment: I don't care about it =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
    parentElement.animate({
        "height" : "hide", "opacity" : 0.0
    }, { duration : "slow"}, "linear", callback);
```

That second parameter? [It's supposed to be either a string or a number](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate). When you pass in an object, jQuery doesn't know what to do with it. Switch to this:

```
    parentElement.animate({
        "height" : "hide", "opacity" : 0.0
    }, "slow", "linear", callback);
```

...and it'll work just fine.

Comment: Dead on. I just figured it out and came to post...darn you for being smarter and faster =P